# LibGdx TextField - How to hide Keyboard when not focused?

Tags: libgdx, keyboard

I'm creating a registration screen for my game. I implemented textfields and input is getting correctly. But when I click elsewhere after text is entered, the keyboard stays visible and does not hide automatically, even when a new screen is loaded. Is there any listener methods for hiding the keyboard?

Right now I did a workaround by calling the `setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(false)` in the sign up and sign in buttons. But I want the keyboard to hide right when it is unfocussed. Is it possible?

**UPDATE:**

Actually I thought when I click elsewhere the textfield focus changed automatically but that's not the case. The cursor keeps blinking even after the keyboard is hidden explicitly. I edited the correct answer to include this.

Comment: Did you try to add FocusListener to an input text field?

Comment: I tried that but it's not working. May be I used it wrong: http://hastebin.com/poravupoto.java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void keyboardFocusChanged(FocusEvent event, Actor actor, boolean focused) {
    super.keyboardFocusChanged(event, actor, focused);
    if (!focused)
        setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(false);
}
```

Otherwise you could go for a better work around. You place a big clickable transparent actor behind everything. When you click anywhere next to your buttons, textfields, etc this field will be triggered and you can get rid of your keyboard ;).

**EDIT:**

The textfield will remain focused even after this, so the cursor will keep blinking and we don't want that. As mentioned here:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Flash-Flex-ActionScript/TextField/ToremovefocusfromatextfieldyoushouldassignStagefocusthenullvalue.htm

you should also unfocus the stage along with hiding the keyboard.

```
stage.unfocusAll()
```

Comment: Setting a clickable actor (in my case a dialog) does not do the trick for me. I enable touchable and print "dialog" on every click, so taht works. However it does not remove focus from my textfields

Comment: Wow thanks! :) `keyboardFocusChanged` didn't work. But the second method did the trick. I put a big button in the background and placed the `setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(false)` in its listener and added the button to stage above all others.

Comment: Hehe, sometimes you have to think a bit out of the box ;).

Comment: @iQue Are you trying to do the same thing as me??

Comment: @BlackPanda Ya I am, but I tried to use my table in the background instead of an invisible button, tried an invisible button and works like a charm :) Odd that you have to make such a weird workaround for such a common scenario

Comment: @iQue great! :) Yeah, such simple thing should have been taken care of by the framework.

Comment: @BlackPanda Could you maybe add the code for ur button and how u added it without distorting the other actors and stuff? :)

Comment: @iQue It's pretty small addition actually. Add this code at the top, before adding any other buttons: http://hastebin.com/otoveqelam.avrasm

Comment: @BlackPanda Thanks, same thing I did :) I guess Im just having problems since my textfields are inside a dialog that pops up, which takes up most of the space on the screen.

Comment: @iQue What if you set a ClickListener on the dialog itself? `dialog.addListener(new ClickListener(){...});`. I did not test this but logically it should not register a click if there is a button or or other actor in front of it. So whenever you click somewhere in the dialog where there is no actor it should trigger and you can hide the keyboard.

Comment: @MennoGouw First thing I tried :) Apparently touching the text-fields inside the dialog trigger that clickListener aswell, so setting `stage.unfocusAll` wil unfocus the texfield just as I press it. And setting FocusChangeListener does not work, I guess since its just a dialog.

Comment: @iQue And you are sure that if you set a button filling the dialog box and doing it that way does not work? Are you 100% sure your button fills the dialog box? Give it a temporary texture so you can visually see that the button fills up the area.

Comment: @MennoGouw I tried setting just that, but it distorted everything else inside the dialog, since it tries to position itself relative to the button, and not on top of it. But Ill do some more testing

Comment: @iQue Well, I believe if you have your button in a different group/table/cell/etc and have that added to your dialog box first you can add another group/table/cell/etc next and they should not interfere with each other. I overlayed groups and tables in the past without problems.

Comment: I posted my solution in case anyone ran into my problem :)

Comment: @iQue Good to hear you finally worked it out.

Answer (score 3):

Menno Gouw's answer is correct and is probably the way to go in most cases, but just in case someone runs into my problem where that solution might distort the positioning of other actors I thought I'd post how I solved it.

First Create an "invisible" button:

```
ImageButtonStyle style = new ImageButtonStyle();
style.up = null;
style.down = null;
cancelFocusButton = new ImageButton(style);
```

Second, add your listener to the invisible button:

```
cancelFocusButton.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        Gdx.input.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(false);
        stage.unfocusAll();
    }
});
```

Third, add this button to a stack together with the table that holds all your other actors (Textfields, labels, button etc):

```
Stack stack = new Stack();
stack.addActor(cancelFocusButton);
stack.addActor(tempTable);
```

Lastly add your stack to your "main table" (in my case the ContentTable inside the dialog):

```
getContentTable().add(stack).expand().fill();
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do the same thing and went for an extremely simple solution in the end and it seems to work well.

I created my own StageExtension class that extends Stage (for other reasons), but within this I simply override the touchDown method adding 2 lines;

```
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    super.unfocusAll();
    Gdx.input.setOnscreenKeyboardVisible(false);
    return super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
}
```

You can of course add some simple checks in there to match your needs, but this works perfectly for me.